# Buck Converter load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

In normal theory, when the load increase then the current drawn by it also increases. But in case of Buck converter, load is connected parallel to capacitor. When the load increasees then current pass through it will reduce. If we have heavy load then how less current will work?

Comment: "*When the load increasees then current pass through it will reduce.*" I assume you are trying to say that less current will pass through the capacitor?

Comment: I means to say that less current will flow through load as the load increases. But large current is needed for lager load.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. More load (i.e. lower resistance) means more current at the same voltage.

Comment: More load. I means to say more resistance. As resistance is real load.

Comment: Infinite load resistance is zero load. So the problem is in your understanding of what "increased load" means.

Comment: Means adding more resistance in series with the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

The Input and Output Current of a Buck Converter depends on it's efficiency. A theoretical Buck Converter with Ideal Components will have an efficiency of 100%.

Efficiency = Pout/Pin = (Vout x Iout) / (Vin x Iin)

If you know your maximum input current, then you can find your max output current. As you add more loads in parallel with Vout, this doesn't mean that Iout will increase to it's max value.

For example, if you have a 12V power supply that can deliver a maximum of 2A of current and you are stepping the voltage down to 3V using a Buck Converter, that means your max output current will be 8A. How much of that current you use depends on your load.

Now if you tried to draw more than 8A on the output, your input supply may overload, and you could damage it depending on the power supply. But it could also have some type of over current protection, and will just turn off in that case.

Comment: I mean to say that when load increases then less current starts to flow through it and more through the capacitor which seems contradiction to the fact that high load draws more current

Comment: When you have a larger resistance, your capacitor current isn't going to increase. Since The power in = power out, your input current will also decrease. Because the power size is decreasing, the output power is adjusted, and the capacitor current isn't affected.